# WPF Text Trimming

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

I'm using WPF's `TextBlock` for running text animation.
I do so by setting the `TranslateTransform.X` from `-ActualWidth` to `ActualWidth`.

Everything works fine but there is one little problem:
The text in the `TextBlock.Text` property is trimmed to fit the initial size window.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtRunning" 
           TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
           Text="very long text here...">
```

I tried to set: `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` but it replaced the trimming with three dots (...).

I would like to know how can I replace these three dots with the full text (no trimming text).

Comment: What is the parent panel of this `TextBlock`?

Comment: The Width of the `TextBlock` is being limited by whatever the parent panel is. What type of panel is this? You'll probably want a panel type that doesn't automatically resize its children, such as a `Canvas`

Comment: It seems you are trying to create a marquee: http://weblogs.asp.net/razan/creating-marquee-scrolling-text-in-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the size of your `TextBlock` is being constrained by its parent container.  Wrapping it in a `Canvas` should allow it to extend beyond the right edge of the window and give you the scrolling banner effect you want.  That should be the only change necessary; you would still apply the animated transform directly to the `TextBlock`.

As an aside, there are some attached properties in `TextOptions` that you might want to look at if you will be drawing animated text, e.g., `TextHintingMode`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the `TextBlock` to trim text, then don't set `TextTrimming`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtRunning" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="very long text here...">
```

Setting `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` means that any text that doesn't fit within the `TextBlock` will be replaced with an ellipsis, "...".